# Suggested edit review shows buttons shoved to the side

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits, design

This is *probably* due to the Stack Overflow for Teams sidebar.

The **rendered output** and **markdown** toggle buttons seem to have moved to the side and do not show the full text.

[image]

**Note**:

I could see the issue in latest stable Chrome as well as Firefox in macOS v10.12 (Sierra).

It is not reproducible if I go to the link without login (i.e. may not be reproducible for users without a Teams profile).

Comment: It's caused by "unified-themes.css" applying `.question-summary{display: flex;}`. The `question-summary` class is used on a various different pages for "question summaries" which have a variety of formats and HTML structures. Applying `display: flex;` is bound to mess some things up. This is one of them. To the best of my knowledge, the "unified-themes.css" CSS file is only loaded for those who have signed up for themes.

Comment: @Makyen _signed up for themes_  I assume you meant teams?

Comment: Yep, in my prior comment "those who have signed up for themes" should be "those who have signed up for a Team (aka Channel)".

Comment: I can reproduce this on Chrome 65 on macOS 10.13.2 High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks. [Mayken's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366181/suggested-edit-review-shows-buttons-shoved-to-the-side#comment575497_366181) pretty much says it all.